# Django-CKEditor with ACE

Tags: django, django-ckeditor

I'm using `Django-CKEditor` in a project and I want to include code editing.  I know `CKEditor` has an addon [PBCKCode](http://ckeditor.com/addon/pbckcode) which enables code editor functionality for languages.  Is there anyway to use this addon with `Django-CKEditor`?